# Reputation graph in network profile could have clarifcation of "All Accounts"

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, reputation-graph

My reputation graph has options to select "Top 5 Accounts" or "All Accounts":

[image]

But selecting the "All Accounts" only shows ones with 200+ rep. This is understandable - I don't want a graph with 66 sites on it, but could the text be made clearer that it is only accounts with 200 plus, maybe a tooltip, text with a smaller font below it or even a `[?]` icon that you can hover over?